# Sublime - Change background color based on Build System

Tags: sublimetext

There is a question asking how to change background color based on file type, [Sublime 2 -changing background color based on file type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136714/sublime-2-changing-background-color-based-on-file-type).

Something close to this came to my mind. I was thinking in change the background color based on current Sublime Build System. Would it be possible?

For example, Red means Python, Green means LaTeX, Blue means Automatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some [built-in commands](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/commands.html#cmd-list) to run a specified build system or to set a particular one as the active build system, so you could possibly set an [`EventListener`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener) to listen for the `set_build_system` command and fire off a plugin to change the current view's background (or all the views in a window, or all views in all windows) when the build system is changed.

Here's a brief proof of concept:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class ListenToBuildSystem(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_window_command(self, window, command, args):
        if command == "set_build_system":
            window.run_command("toggle_minimap")
```

This toggles the display of the minimap every time the build system is changed.